# JS Copy to Clipboard Discontiguous section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS code for copying to clipboard:

```
function copyAll(copyEl){
    var textToCopy = $(copyEl)[0];

    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(textToCopy);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);


    try {
        // Now that text is selected, execute the copy command
        var copyRet = document.execCommand('copy');
        var msg = copyRet ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
        $('#copyResult').stop(true, true).fadeOut(0).html('Copied to clipboard').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(3000);

        // Remove the selections
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

        console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
    }
    catch(err) {
        $('#copyResult').stop(true, true).fadeOut(0).html('Oops, unable to copy').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(3000);
        console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
    }
}
```

When this function is executed, I get this error and log in the console:

```
Discontiguous selection is not supported.
Copy command was successful
```

at this line:

```
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

And the text is not copied.

So, how come I get an error, still I get `Copy command was successful`?

Also, this behaviour is not observed always. Sometimes, I do not get this error, and at some other times, I get this error but still the text is copied to clipboard.

I am working only on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a bug on Chrome's side. Check if it works properly now. More details [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=353069#c4).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this error is thrown is because of the Selection Object's `rangeCount` is not zero.

As @dropout has mentioned the [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=353069#c4), it will avoid addRange to Selection Object if it already has selection range.

And the message 'Copy command was successful' is received because of the non null selection range. So whatever was under selection was added.

To solve this, you should check for the rangeCount. And if rangeCount is not 0, you can fire `window.getSelection().empty()` or `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()`, then only  `addRange` and go for the `copy` command.

```
function copyAll(copyEl){
  var textToCopy = $(copyEl)[0];

  var range = document.createRange();

  if(range.rangeCount > 0){
    range.removeAllRanges();
  }
  range.selectNode(textToCopy);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);


  try {
    // Now that text is selected, execute the copy command
    var copyRet = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = copyRet ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    $('#copyResult').stop(true, true).fadeOut(0).html('Copied to clipboard').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(3000);

    // Remove the selections
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

    console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
  }
  catch(err) {
      $('#copyResult').stop(true, true).fadeOut(0).html('Oops, unable to copy').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(3000);
      console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }

}
```